# django-python create Multidimensional Array in views.py

Tags: python, django, multidimensional-array

In models.py:

```
class PUser(models.Model):
        phone = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        email = models.TextField()
        txt = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to create Multidimensional Array for that.

For now this is what I have in the function in views.py:

```
def main(request):
    users = []
    for i in range (5):
        for a in range(3):
            users[i][a] = PUser.objects.all()
return render(request, 'main.html', {'users': users})
```

But I know its not correct, its not working.

How should I edit it?

And how the code in the main.html should be?

I was thinking about something like `{{ users[2][3] }}` for example. How the code should be? (I have read same questions but was not helpful for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `PUser.objects.all()` returns an array of `PUser` object, you just have to write :

```python
def main(request):
    users = PUsers.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'users': users})
```

and in your template, iterate on `users` array :

```python
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.phone }}
    {{ user.email }}
    {{ user.txt }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you wanna print a specific user, you can by specifying its index :

```python
{{ users[3].phone }}
{{ users[3].email }}
{{ users[3].txt }}
# or
{{ users.3.phone }}
{{ users.3.email }}
{{ users.3.txt }}
```

Comment: But as I noticed I want to use something like `{{ users[2][3] }}`. I want to choose the index I want and put it in different places in my file code. I dont want to print all of them one after an other in a certain place, so dont want to use "for loop". I want to be able to select which index be printed in which place in the code.

Comment: I add an example to print a specific user :)

Comment: By using `{{ users[3].phone }}` I faced with this error: `Could not parse the remainder: '[3].phone' from 'user[3].phone'`

Comment: use `users[3]` variable and not `user[3]`

Comment: I edited but the same error: `Could not parse the remainder: '[3].phone' from 'users[3].phone'`

Comment: try with `users.3.phone`, do you use django template or jinja?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109442/discussion-between-louis-barranqueiro-and-niloofar).